# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: angularFireAuthProvider <- angularFireAuth

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I use the following libraries in .html

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.11/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.4.1/firebase-simple-login.js'>
</script>
```

while trying to integrate a simple chat into my site:

```
angular.module('habitApp.controllers.chatRoom', ['firebase'])
.controller('ChatController', 
   function ($scope, $firebase) { 
    var ref = new Firebase('https://xxx.firebaseio.com');
    $scope.messages = $firebase(ref);
    $scope.addMessage = function () {
       $scope.messages.$add({from: $scope.name, body: $scope.msg});
       $scope.msg="";
    };
    });
```

and I got a constant error "Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: angularFireAuthProvider <- angularFireAuth"

Please help.

Comment: angularFireAuth was renamed to $firebaseSimpleLogin. Somewhere (not in your code above) it's being injected as a dependency. Did you copy some code from a tutorial? Chances are, a quick search for angularFireAuth can find the dependency injection for you.

Comment: Yes, there were instances of angularFireAuth in my login service. When I substituted them with $firebaseSimpleLogin (library was  linked in index.html) I got Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $firebaseSimpleLoginProvider <- $firebaseSimpleLogin <- loginService. Does $firebaseSimpleLogin has different methods?